# php problem with using a get value. works on one part of the page but not the other

Tags: php

im working on my crud skills, but im having some trouble. the first page shows a list of all blog posts, when the user clicks on read more it sends the specific posts id through the url and is recieved by the destination page which uses that id to display the single post/ heres the code for that part. it actually works fine

```
function display_single_post($title,$author,$date,$image,$content){
                        $main_page_blog_html  =         "<h2>
                                                            <a href='#'>%s</a>
                                                        </h2>
                                                        <p class='lead'>
                                                            by <a href='index.php'>%s</a>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Posted on %s</p>
                                                        <hr>
                                                        <img class='img-responsive' src='images/%s'>
                                                        <hr>
                                                        <p>%s</p>

                                                        <hr>
                                                        <hr>";

                            printf("{$main_page_blog_html}",$title,$author,$date,$image,$content);


if(isset($_GET["id"])){
                        $id = $_GET["id"];

                        $stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $id");
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                            $post_title = $row["post_title"];
                            $post_author = $row["post_author"];
                            $post_date = date('F j, Y \a\t g:ia', strtotime( $row["post_date"] ));
                            $post_image = $row["post_image"];
                            $post_content = $row["post_content"];
                            $id = $row["post_id"];

                            display_single_post($post_title,$post_author,$post_date,$post_image,$post_content);

                        }
                    }
```

like i said this all works fine. the get value is recieved and loads the post. the problem is when i try to use that $_get id in a query to insert a comment. all this code is on the one page im just showing the php without the html. anyway heres the code to insert the comment

```
if(isset($_POST["create_comment"])){
                        global $connect;

                        $post_id = $_GET["id"];

                        $comment_author = $_POST["comment_author"];
                        $author_email = $_POST["author_email"];
                        $comment_content = $_POST["comment_content"];
                        $comment_status = "pending";
```

edit with all the code

```
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
            <div class="col-md-8">

                <h1 class="page-header">
                    Page Heading
                    <small>Secondary Text</small>
                </h1>

                <!-- First Blog Post -->
                <?php 

                   $connect = new db();

                    if(isset($_POST["create_comment"])){
                        global $connect;
                        echo "hello";
                        $post_id = $_GET["id"];

                        $comment_author = $_POST["comment_author"];
                        $author_email = $_POST["author_email"];
                        $comment_content = $_POST["comment_content"];
                        $comment_status = "pending";

                        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(comment_post_id, comment_author, comment_email, comment_content, comment_status)
                                VALUES(:a,:b,:c,:d,:e)";
                        $stmt = $connect->link->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bindvalue(":a",$post_id);
                        $stmt->bindvalue(":b", $comment_author);
                        $stmt->bindvalue(":c",$author_email);
                        $stmt->bindvalue(":d",$comment_content);
                        $stmt->bindvalue(":e",$comment_status);
                        $stmt->execute();
                    }




                    function display_single_post($title,$author,$date,$image,$content){
                        $main_page_blog_html  =         "<h2>
                                                            <a href='#'>%s</a>
                                                        </h2>
                                                        <p class='lead'>
                                                            by <a href='index.php'>%s</a>
                                                        </p>
                                                        <p><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> Posted on %s</p>
                                                        <hr>
                                                        <img class='img-responsive' src='images/%s'>
                                                        <hr>
                                                        <p>%s</p>

                                                        <hr>
                                                        <hr>";

                            printf("{$main_page_blog_html}",$title,$author,$date,$image,$content);

                    }






                    if(isset($_GET["id"])){
                        $id = $_GET["id"];

                        $stmt = $connect->link->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = $id");
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){

                            $post_title = $row["post_title"];
                            $post_author = $row["post_author"];
                            $post_date = date('F j, Y \a\t g:ia', strtotime( $row["post_date"] ));
                            $post_image = $row["post_image"];
                            $post_content = $row["post_content"];
                            $id = $row["post_id"];

                            display_single_post($post_title,$post_author,$post_date,$post_image,$post_content);

                        }
                    }

                ?>
                <hr>

                <!-- Blog Comments -->

                <!-- Comments Form -->
                <div class="well">
                    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                    <form role="form" method="post" action="post.php">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_author" placeholder="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="author_email" placeholder="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="comment_content"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="create_comment" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <hr>

                <!-- Posted Comments -->

                <!-- Comment -->
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Start Bootstrap
                            <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                        </h4>
                        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Comment -->
                <div class="media">
                    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                        <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Start Bootstrap
                            <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                        </h4>
                        Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                        <!-- Nested Comment -->
                        <div class="media">
                            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                            </a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="media-heading">Nested Start Bootstrap
                                    <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                                </h4>
                                Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End Nested Comment -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi, what is the problem you're having exactly? By that I mean, are you getting an error or the comment simply is not added? Also, it might be helpful to add to your question the html for the form to check it has everything you're requesting in the php.

Comment: sorry, its late and im overworked. in the second code block i posted, its not finding the $_GET["id"] but it is in the first

Comment: I see, if everything is on the same page and you can still see the id on the url, it should work so I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Could you add inside the if statement right at the beginning an echo "hello"; just to make sure you're actually getting inside? If you are, then try and post the whole code if possible.

Comment: @juan v see the edit. i did the echo and it worked but still shows the error

Comment: Hi php-ninja, I see you approved the answer,  thanks for that. Be sure to check the last addition with the PHP_SELF. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code and your comments, I assume the page is called **post.php** and when you first reach the page it has the id on the url like this: **post.php?id=156**.

But once you submit the comments' form, since the action for said form it is simply **post.php** you're losing the id.

You could add the id on the action after post:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

or add a hidden input with the id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

But then you'd have to reach it with $_POST

Another option is to use the SELF for the action like this:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

This will retain the id but also any other get variables you may have on the url.

**//EDIT**

This is a simplification of the probelm which is working, if you visit post.php?id=456 (or any number) and then press Submit, you get the proper response:

```
<!-- First Blog Post -->
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST["create_comment"])){

        $post_id = $_GET["id"];
        echo "The id is: $post_id";

        // gets comment and inserts into the db

    }

    if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        // calls display_single_post    
    }

?>

<!-- Comments Form -->
<div class="well">
    <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
    <form role="form" method="post" action="post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="create_comment" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i pre-emptively approved your answer. i tried adding the hidden input. got an error then i tried appending it to the action like so ```<form role="form" method="post" action="post.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"> ``` and it gave me an error undefined variable $id. is this referring to where i set the get variable to $id in the second code block? perhaps its a scope problem?

Comment: First, check the line number for the error. If it says undefined variable $id for the line of the form then indeed it means it cannot find where it was defined in the script earlier which is weird because you are defining it inside  the isset($_GET['id']) that should be passing anyway as long as you have the id in the url. You could simply say echo $_GET['id']; directly but something else seems to be wrong. I'll add some extra code with the simplification of the problem to check it.

Comment: If you still can't get it to work, post the full page and the exact error message you're getting (with the line number and everything), just be sure you have a number in the url like post.php?id=456 when testing.

Comment: thanks man been a long day. i have remedied the situation by putting the query into a seperate file called add_comment. then when i appended the id to the action it worked and updated the table